# How do I assign output of a function to a string variable?

Tags: python, function, variables, printing

I'm trying to create a 3 x 3 board with number from 1-9 with this function:

```
board =(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
def board_display():
    print("_" *6)
    for row in range(3):
        print("".join((f"|{board[row*3+ position]}" for position in range(3))) + "|")
        print("_" *6)
board_display()
```

Output:

```
|1|2|3|
______
|4|5|6|
______
|7|8|9|
______
```

Now I want to assign this board to a variable, say "New_board", so that I can use this variable in other functions. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want board and New_board to represent the numbers on a 3x3 board, or represent a picture of those numbers like the one you include in your question.   As @j1-lee suggests,  if it's the latter, then rewrite board_display to return a string that, when printed, looks like the picture you want.   I think my preference would be for the former (the list of 9 numbers) and then define board_display to take as an argument the "board" (list of 9 numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
board='\n'.join(['|'+'|'.join(map(str,range(1+3*j,4+3*j)))+'|\n'+'-'*6
                 for j in range(3)])
```

This is the result:

```
>>> print(board)
|1|2|3|
------
|4|5|6|
------
|7|8|9|
------
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should simply append all lines to a list and then join it with newlines (as to mimic the behaviour of `print()`). Like this:

```py
def board_display():
    res = []
    res.append("_" *6)
    for row in range(3):
        res.append("".join((f"|{board[row*3+ position]}" for position in range(3))) + "|")
        res.append("_" *6)

    return "\n".join(res)
```

---

Although I highly advice against it, you could use [`redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) from [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html). Then your code would look like this:

```py
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

res = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(res):
   board_display()

output = res.getvalue()  # Turn the StringIO() into 'str'
```

Like I said though, you should definitely use the previously mentioned method (since you are able to modify the function) - but take this as a fun fact and hidden gem in the standard library .